# Show user specific classes and assignments in jQuery mobile app

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-mobile, global-variables

I'm currently working on a mobile app using jQuery Mobile and the MVC framework.
It functions as a task/assignment manager that allows users to enter class information (name, instructor, description, etc.) and assignment information for each class (title, note, dueDate, etc.)

I have created a login page using session variables and can successfully login. Upon logging in, I have a default action="list_assignments", which takes all the class names and turns them into dividers for a listview with the assignments under each class.

My problem is that when logging in I see every assignment across all users.

I have 3 tables in MySQL,

- Assignments (assign_id[PKey and AutoInc], assign_title, note, dueDate, user_id, class_id)
- Classes (class_id[Pkey & AI], class_name, class_instructor, class_description, user_id)
- Users (user_id[Pkey & AI], username, password)

assignment_tracker/index.php (controller)

```
if ($action == 'list_assignments') {

    // Get the current user ID
   @ $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if (!isset($user_id)) {
        $user_id = 1;
    }
    // Get the current class ID
   @ $class_id = $_GET['class_id'];
    if (!isset($class_id)) {
        $class_id = 1;
    }

    // Get assignment and class data
    $class_name = get_class_name($class_id);
    $classes = get_classes();

    // needs to be looped for each class within assignment_list.php
    $assignments = get_assignments_by_class($class_id);

    // Display the assignment list, or build "the view"
    include('view/assignment_list.php');


}
```

assignment_tracker/view/assignment_list.php

```
    <?php include ('header.php'); ?>

    <?php print $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>

    <div data-role="content" id="assignment_list">
    <!-- create 2 foreach loops, 1 for classes to be listed and organized by id in list dividers and another for listing individual assignments within each class -->   
     <ul data-role="listview">

     <!--classes loop-->
     <?php foreach ($classes as $class) : ?>

    <li data-role="list-divider"><?php echo $class['class_name']; ?></li>

    <?php $assignments=get_assignments_by_class($class['class_id']); ?> 
    <?php foreach ($assignments as $assignment) : ?><!--assignments loop-->
    <?php print'<li><a href="index.php?action=show_assign_details&assign_id='.$assignment['assign_id'].'&class_id='.$assignment['class_id'].'">'.$assignment['assign_title'].'</a></li>';?>
    <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/assignments loop-->
    <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/classes loop-->

     </ul>      
    </div><!--/data-role="content"-->


    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

assignment_tracker/model/class_db.php

```
    <?php
function get_classes() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM classes
              ORDER BY class_id';
    $result = $db->query($query);
    return $result;
}

function get_class_name($class_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM classes
              WHERE class_id = $class_id";
    $class = $db->query($query);
    $class = $class->fetch();
    $class_name = $class['class_name'];
    return $class_name;
}
```

assignment_tracker/model/assignment_db.php

```
<?php
function get_assignments() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM assignments
              ORDER BY assign_ID';
    $assignments = $db->query($query);
    return $assignments;
}

function get_assignments_by_class($class_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM assignments
              WHERE assignments.class_id = '".$class_id."'
              ORDER BY assign_id";
    $assignments = $db->query($query);
    return $assignments;
}
```

I tried creating a query that would find the assignments according to the user's id, but when I implemented a solution in the foreach loops I got an invalid argument for foreach error which means that one of my inputs was not an array. I've been stuck on this for many many hours so I figured it was time to use my resources and ask for help.

If you need any more information please let me know and I thank everyone who helps in advance.

UPDATE:

Hi everyone,

I figured out how to get a result by hardcoding a user id into my query. At first I thought it wasn't returning an array for some reason, but upon testing in phpMyAdmin my query works fine when a user_id is hardcoded.

I created a new function in class_db.php to return only the classes where the user_id matches. I'm trying to use the `$_SESSION['user_id']` variable I set in the controller upon login.

```
function get_classes_by_user($user_id) {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM classes
      WHERE user_id = 1
          ORDER BY class_id';
$result = $db->query($query);
return $result;
}
```

index.php

```
    if ($action == 'list_assignments') {

    // Get the current class ID
   @ $class_id = $_GET['class_id'];
    if (!isset($class_id)) {
        $class_id = 1;
    }
    // Get the current user ID
   @ $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if (!isset($user_id)) {
        $user_id = 1;
    }

    // Get assignment and class data
    $class_name = get_class_name($class_id);
    $classes = get_classes();

    //new function being called with resultant array stored in $userclasses
    $userclasses = get_classes_by_user($user_id);

    // needs to be looped for each class within assignment_list.php
    $assignments = get_assignments_by_class($class_id);

    // Display the assignment list, or build "the view"
    include('view/assignment_list.php');

}
```

assignment_list.php

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
<?php print $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>
        <div data-role="content" id="assignment_list">
            <!-- create 2 foreach loops, 1 for classes to be listed and organized by id in list dividers and another for listing individual assignments within each class -->   
            <ul data-role="listview">

            <!--classes loop-->

            <?php foreach ($userclasses as $class) : ?>

                <li data-role="list-divider"><?php echo $class['class_name']; ?></li>

                <?php $assignments=get_assignments_by_class($class['class_id']); ?> 
                <?php foreach ($assignments as $assignment) : ?><!--assignments loop-->
                <?php print'<li><a href="index.php?action=show_assign_details&assign_id='.$assignment['assign_id'].'&class_id='.$assignment['class_id'].'">'.$assignment['assign_title'].'</a></li>';?>
                <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/assignments loop-->
            <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/classes loop-->

            </ul>       
        </div><!--/data-role="content"-->


<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I changed the $classes in the foreach loop above to $userclasses to match the new function.

Anyone have any ideas? I know I'm very close to figuring this out! Once again thanks for your help!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @teresko Thanks for the tip, could you please be more specific as to where I went wrong here with regards to the deprecated `mysql_*` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after messing around with my app for a while, I finally got it to work.

In my index.php file I set the `$_SESSION['user_id']` to `$user_id` and added the `get_classes_by_user($user_id)` function and returned the result to `$userclasses`

```
    if ($action == 'list_assignments') {

    // Get the current class ID
   @ $class_id = $_GET['class_id'];
    if (!isset($class_id)) {
        $class_id = 1;
    }

    // Get the current user ID
   @ $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if (!isset($user_id)) {
        $user_id = 1;
    }

    // Get assignment and class data
    $class_name = get_class_name($class_id);
    $classes = get_classes();

    $userclasses = get_classes_by_user($user_id);

    // needs to be looped for each class within assignment_list.php
    $assignments = get_assignments_by_class($class_id);

    // Display the assignment list, or build "the view"
    include('view/assignment_list.php');
    }
```

In class_db.php, I noticed that I had a problem with my query.

Original with single quotes does not work

```
function get_classes_by_user($user_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM classes
              WHERE user_id = $user_id
              ORDER BY class_id';
    $result = $db->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

Updated with double quotes and working

```
function get_classes_by_user($user_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM classes
              WHERE user_id = $user_id
              ORDER BY class_id";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

I looked up the difference and have determined that if a query has a variable in it, it should be wrapped in double quotes (Don't quote me, lol). I have seen a query with the variables wrapped in curly braces {}  as well, I tried it myself and it makes no difference when using single quotes, at least for me anyway.